# How refresh observable every 30 seconds?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, observable, angularfire

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-geo',
  templateUrl:   <img  mat-card-image [src]="profileUrl | async ">

  export class GeoComponent implements OnInit {
    date;
    profileUrl: Observable<string>;

    constructor(private tempService: TemperatureService, private humService: HumiditeService, public authService: AuthService,private database: AngularFireDatabase, private storage: AngularFireStorage,private router: Router)
    {
      const ref = this.storage.ref('live/live.jpg');
      this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL(); 
    }
  }
})
```

My image in Firebase is overwriting every 30 seconds. How I can get the value of `this.profileUrl` every 30 seconds and save it to Firebase ?

How I use a timer to refresh my observable every 30 seconds?

Comment: Set timer to to get new paths from the Firebase every 30 seconds through `HttpClient`, and subscribe to result.

Comment: I'm not sure what you try do here. But you know that the valueChanged catch every change you make in your database document? So after this catch you can subscribe and set your value.

Comment: yes it is that why i would prefiere write the download url in firebase but i have juste the location //gs...

Comment: Some one can show me how to use timer and httpsClient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of RxJS [Interval](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html) and [TakeWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operators will do the job.

Something like this [StackBlitz project example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53500447):

```
const source = interval(30000).pipe(
  takeWhile(() => { return true }) // here you can have some logic to stop the requests
);
const subscription = source.subscribe(
  (x) => {
    // your code goes here
  },
  function (err) {
    console.log('Error: ' + err);
  },
  function () {
    console.log('Completed');
  });
```

Comment: hi. thanks i put this code : const ref = this.storage.ref('live/live.jpg');
this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL(); ?

Comment: I'm glad to help. Just an important issue using this, when your component destroy, kill this observer so it won't keep firing till the app gets killed

Comment: How i can to this ? In effect i have some troubles when an another image is coming...

Comment: I've updated the sample project to show you how to kill the subscription. notice that when moving from main to child, main is stopping writing to console, while when moving from child to main, child is still writing to console. the code you need to focus on located in main.component.ts where it is implementing OnDestroy and unsubscribing the observer.

Comment: thanks i will workd on this tomorrow thank you a lot